# How to add java mock objects to hashset?

Tags: mockito

I want to create a set that holds mock java objects.Like the following

```
MyObject objectA = mock(MyObject.class);
when(objectA.getName()).thenReturn("nameA");

MyObject objectB = mock(MyObject.class);
when(objectB.getName()).thenReturn("nameB");

MyObject objectC = mock(MyObject.class);
when(objectC.getName()).thenReturn("nameC");

Set<MyObject> mySet = new HashSet<>();
mySet.add(objectA);
mySet.add(objectB);
mySet.add(objectC);
mySet.size();// this will be "1" instead of "3"
```

I want the size of the set to be "3" instead of "1".

I know that when adding an object to set it will verify hashcode of the object. In this case all of my mock objects have same hash code so the set is able to hold only one value.

I had also tried the following

```
int someRandomInt = 12345;
when(objectA.hashCode()).thenReturn(someRandomInt):
```

But Mockito fails to stub out private final methods.

How can I have a set that holds different mock objects ?

Comment: i tried it ... for me it outputs '3' ... btw. you can put different objects with equal hashcodes into a hashset ... it's important that those object are not equal to each other with respect to the  equals() Method.

Comment: please share the whole code (MyObject)

Comment: @Andre R you are right. MyObject class is extending a abstract class that was using was overriding the hash code (which i didn't realize it). Thanks for ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IdentityHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html) class instead of HashSet. It uses reference comparison instead of equals methods so objects with different addresses will not be considered equal by this class.